# "I employed you as a cook."

Tags: ambiguity

> I employed you as a cook.

> 1. I’m a cook and I employed you
> 2. I employed you and you are a cook

Can *you were employed as a cook* also be ambiguous like above? Precisely, can it mean I’m a cook and I employed you?

Comment: It would at least need a comma to have the first meaning. "I employed you, as a cook, to wash dishes for me" - but that would hardly be idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. I employed you as a cook.

1. I’m a cook and I employed you
2. I employed you and you are a cook

Q. Can you’re employed as a cook also be ambiguous like above? Precisely, can it mean I’m a cook and I employed you?

In a direct answer to your question I would say No, **"its not ambiguous"** and it "**does not have the meaning of "I’m a cook and I employed you"**.

---

**What is the meaning of "*I employed you as a cook*"**

The meaning of *I employed you as a cook* is **"I gave you a job of doing the cooking"**.
However the literal meaning of  "*I employed you as a cook*" is not helpful to find the meaning of this statement. Any conversation containing this phrase would add some context. Remember when, I employed you as a cook, and now here we are at your retirement party... But **most likely it would be used as a reprimand**.

**Use**

It is not the type of phrase that would find a common use except as a reprimand.

I employed you as a cook but now want you to be a lawyer/dressmaker/maid are unlikely statements.

However it is the type of commonly used phrase that is used as a reprimand.
It implies that the employed person is doing something they are not employed to do, that he/she has been doing something outside of their remit or perhaps a non acceptable task during their working hours.

Why are you fixing that car? **I employed you as a cook**, not a mechanic.

Meaning "**you have a job to do, for me, it is cooking**" not fixing cars.

What are you doing on that press? I employed you as a tool setter not a machine operator!

---

**The meaning of the two sentences you gave as examples**.

I’m a cook and I employed you = I am a cook (my professing is cooking) and you had/have a job working for me. (to do what, is not specified)

I employed you and you are a cook =  I gave you employment and your professing is cooking (to do what job is not specified, only implied)

---

**employed**; adjective; having a job working for a company or another person:

**employ**; verb; to have someone work or do a job for you and pay them for it

**employment**; noun; the fact of someone being paid to work for a company or organization:

All ref CED [employed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/employed)

Comment: What about ‘I did employment of you as a cook

Comment: I hired you as a cook? Hired = to employ someone or pay someone to do a particular job:

Comment: Accepted or not, I can't make head or tail of this answer.

Comment: @user01101  **I did employment of you as a cook** is not idiomatic, because we don't say "do employment".

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Sorry, please try this edit.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

**You were employed as a cook** is unambiguous. It always carries the meaning "You were paid to do the job of a cook."

I will also say that "I employed you as a cook" meaning "I'm a cook and I employed you" is an awkward phrasing that most people wouldn't use. They would flip it around and say "As a cook, I employed you."

Answer (score 2):

Most native speakers would understand that the prepositional phrase "as a cook" applies as an adjunct not to the subject "I" but to the object "you". This is simply due to proximity within the sentence. If you wanted the phrase "as a cook" to act as an adjuct to "I", you would say:

> I, as a cook, employed you.

or

> As a cook, I employed you.

The proximity rule is not universal, but if two or more possible nouns both make sense, people will generally think the prepositional phrase applies to the closest one within the sentence.